# Save sub Integer in Array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays, int

I want to save an integer type value in array.
Here is a code.

```
int a,arr[5];

cout<<"Enter a Number  ";
cin >> a;
```

Suppose user enter the value `73972` This value save in `arr` like this.

```
arr[0] = 7;
arr[1] = 3;
.. .. .. ..
.. .. .. ..
arr[4] = 2;
```

How can I do that.???

Comment: read it is as a string, not an int.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate reversely on the array and each time divide the number by 10 and store the reminder on the array.

```
for(int i=4; i>=0; i--)
{
    arr[i] = a % 10;
    a /= 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Read a string and break it into digits.

Answer (score 0):

First of all integer values can have more than 5 digits.

You can get the number of digits that an object of type int can contain by using expression

```
std::numeric limits<int>::digits10 + 1
```

class std::numeric_limits is declared in header `<limits>`

Also take into account that if a number contains less digits than the size of the array then you need some mark that will determine the end of the number in the array.

I would advice you to use a character array instead of an array of integers in which the terminating zero will determine the end of the number.

If you want to use an integer array then the code could look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <limits>

int main()
{
   int arr[std::numeric_limits<int>::digits10 + 1];
   int a;

   std::cout << "Enter a Number  ";
   std::cin >> a;

   int n = 0;

   do
   {
      arr[n++] = a % 10;
   } while ( a /= 10 );

   std::reverse( arr, arr + n );

   for ( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) std::cout << arr[i] << ' ';
   std::cout << std::endl;
}
```